# How can i copy tmux output to system clipboard?

Tags: copy, clipboard, tmux

I want to copy a large section to the file in tmux. Then I enter the tmux vi mode, and copy the selected strings. However, the system clipboard is empty. How can I copy the selected strings to system clipboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a local instance of tmux, you could add a binding like this:
`bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | clipboad_manager_of_your_choice"`
Where you would fill in the manager of your choice (`xclip`, `xsel`, if you are on mac `pbcopy`, etc)

Comment: thanks. `tmux show-buffer` also works.

Comment: I used `tmux show-buffer | sudo tee filename` to solve this problem.

Comment: @lancerex not sure why you need the `sudo` there.

Comment: create a file to store the output of `tmux show-buffer`