# Can I pipe tmux buffer to pbcopy?

Tags: macos, clipboard, tmux

I want to do do this in tmux `save-buffer - | pbcopy` or some similar clone of `save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard` so that I can pipe the contents of the tmux clipboard to the os-x clipboard. The problem is that tmux always gives me a syntax hint when I run the command from the tmux command line, or it says `save-buffer - | pbcopy returned 1` when run via keymap and does nothing useful. I've looked at the [linux xclip solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#ICCCM_Selection_Integration) on [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=tmux+save-buffer+-+%7C+xclip+-i+-selection+clipboard) but that didn't help. The tmux man-page and error messages are also kinda useless. Any ideas?

Version info and the like:

- tmux: 1.9a
- OS-X: 10.9.4
- ZSH: 5.0.5

Comment: Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765716/how-can-i-copy-tmux-output-to-system-clipboard

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble with, I found an alternate solution that I'll post as an answer. thoughhttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15715/getting-tmux-to-copy-a-buffer-to-the-clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternate solution to accomplish the same result... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15715/getting-tmux-to-copy-a-buffer-to-the-clipboard
use `copy-pipe` on linux and os-x and I get what I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necroposting.

As a nasty solution I suggest this:

1. copy text by tmux
2. run `cat | pbcopy`
3. paste from tmux
4. Ctr+D

Here you go. `cat` without args just gets input until EOF (which is accomplished by Ctd+D)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) program and this configuration:

**~/.tmux.conf**

```
# Define default shell
set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"

# Copy tmux buffer content to OS clipboard
bind-key y run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

Now I can press `<prefix>+y` to copy text from tmux buffer to OS clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to be able to choose which buffer to copy from:

```
bind y choose-buffer "run-shell \"tmux show-buffer -b %% | pbcopy\" \; display-message \"Copied to system clipboard\""
```